# How can I send and access the map index inside a React child

Tags: javascript, reactjs

after I fetch the array from API, I use the data to build a table using a child component:

```
<tbody>
    {data.map((item, index) => (
      <Row key={index} item={item} deleteMe={deleteChild}/>
    ))}
</tbody>
```

How can I use the above index in the Row component? The child is using the array data like this:

```
return (
  <tr>
    <td>**Here should be the index**</td>
    <td>{item.exerciseName}</td>
    <td>{item.instructions}</td>
  </tr>
  );
```

**UPDATE**
Thank you for all the answers, managed to show the index using your suggestions.

Comment: The `key` attribute is a special attribute that helps React identify components. It is not passed as prop to the actual component. If you want access to the index in `<Row>` you'll have to pass it as addition property `<Row key={index} index={index} ... />`. This allows you to access the index via the props passed to `<Row>`. For more info about `key`, checkout [Why does React need keys?](https://react.dev/learn/rendering-lists#why-does-react-need-keys)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the index as a separate prop.

```
{data.map((item, index) => (
    <Row key={index} item={item} index={index} deleteMe={deleteChild}/>
))}
```

Then, it can be directly accessed inside the `Row` component.

```
function Row({item, index}) {
    return (
      <tr>
        <td>{index}</td>
        <td>{item.exerciseName}</td>
        <td>{item.instructions}</td>
      </tr>
    );
}
```

Working example:

```js
function Row({item, index}) {
  return (
    <tr>
      <td>{index}</td>
      <td>{item.exerciseName}</td>
      <td>{item.instructions}</td>
    </tr>
  );
}
function App() {
  const data = [{exerciseName: 'Name 1', instructions: 'Instructions 1'}, {exerciseName: 'Exercise 2', instructions: 'Instructions 2'}];
  return (
    <table>
      <tbody>
        {data.map((item, index) => (
            <Row key={index} item={item} index={index}/>
        ))}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
}
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(<App/>);
```

```css
table, td {
  border: 1px solid;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The key property is used by React under the hood and is not exposed to you.
You will have to make another prop passed on to the child and access it as you like.

Answer (score 1):

You can use props to do so,

```
<Row key={index} item={item} deleteMe={deleteChild} index={index}/>
```

and inside your child component you can use it by `props.index`

```
return (
    <tr>
        <td>{props.index}</td>
        <td>{item.exerciseName}</td>
        <td>{item.instructions}</td>
    </tr>
);
```